# C Program: newbie trying to pass 2D string array into a function

Tags: c

Programming in C ( with -std=C89), and running into errors trying to pass a character string array into a function.

In `main()`, I've declared the array as follows:

```
#define ROWS 501
#define COLS 101
void my_function( char **);
...
char my_array[ROWS][COLS];
...
my_function(my_array);
```

In `my_function`, I've declared the array as:

```
void my_function( char **my_array )
{
...
}
```

I'm getting this error:

`warning: passing argument 1 of 'my_function' from incompatible pointer type,
note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[101]`

Comment: this link (http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html) should help you.

Comment: wow, that is a good link. thanks @Kunal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A two-dimensional array of characters is still a character array and would have a prototype of `char *my_array`. So just change your function definition to this:

```
void my_function(char *my_array)
```

Note that this will flatten the array. There are different techniques to keep the two-dimensional-ness of the array, an easy way is to use this alternative prototype:

```
void my_function(char my_array[][COLS])
```

Which will preserve your array's dimensions when passed.

`char **my_array` means something completely different (pointer to an array, for example).

Comment: Thanks, If I change the prototype in main() to be `void my_function( char *);` and change the function definition to `void my_function( char *my_array)` I get this error: `warning: passing argument 30 of 'fn_call_master_v1p0' from incompatible pointer type
../Project_Files/myheader.h:59: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char (*)[101]'`

Comment: Thanks, If I change the prototype in main() to be `void my_function( char *my_array[][COLS]);` and change the function definition to `void my_function( char *my_array[][COLS])` I get this warning: `warning: passing argument 1 of 'my_function' from incompatible pointer type, note: expected 'char * (*)[101]' but argument is of type 'char (*)[101]'`

Comment: I didn't say `char *my_array[][COLS]` but `char my_array[][cols]` (notice the extra `*` in your code). You can also use `char (*my_array)[COLS]`, but there's no reason to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `char[]` variable as a `char*`, but you can't pass a `char[][]` as a `char**`.  When you use the argument `char** my_array`, you are saying that `*my_array` has type 'pointer-to-char'.  In reality, it has type 'array-of-char'.  You would use an argument of type `char**` if you were using an array declared like `char* x[];` and each element was a pointer to a dynamically-allocated buffer.

When working with multidimensional arrays, you have to remember that you can only replace the "innermost" dimension of array with `*`.  If you try to abstract away more than one dimension, the compiler won't know how to do the array arithmetic.  If you need a function that takes a multidimensional array with arbitrary sizes in all dimensions, then pass the array as a `void*`, pass the array dimensions as additional arguments, and then do all of the array arithmetic manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function signature with multi dimensional arrays, i.e.:

```
my_fun(char my_array[][COLS]);
```

You might get some out of this:

[A Tutorial on Pointers and Arrays in C](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/a-tutorial-on-pointers-and-arrays-in-c-r1697), see I.e. chapter 7.

---

Edit: I suspect you are trying to do something you do not need.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 501
#define COLS 101

char my_arr[ROWS][COLS];

void foo(char arr[][COLS])
{
    arr[44][23] = 'a';
    printf("foo_1:  %p\n", (void*) arr);
    printf("foo_2:  %p\n", (void*) &arr);
    printf("foo_3:  %p\n", (void*) arr[44]);
    printf("foo_4:  %p\n", (void*) &arr[44]);
}

int main(void)
{
    foo(my_arr);
    printf("my_arr[%03d][%03d] is %c\n", 44, 23, my_arr[44][23]);
    /* my_arr[44][23] is now 'a', (also here)  */

    printf("main_1: %p\n", (void*) my_arr);
    printf("main_2: %p\n", (void*) &my_arr);
    printf("main_3: %p\n", (void*) my_arr[44]);
    printf("main_4: %p\n", (void*) &my_arr[44]);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
foo_1:  0x804a040  <---+
foo_2:  0xbece91f0     |
foo_3:  0x804b19c  <--------+
foo_4:  0x804b19c  <--------+
my_arr[044][023] is a  |    |
main_1: 0x804a040 <----+    |
main_2: 0x804a040 <----+    |
main_3: 0x804b19c <---------+
main_4: 0x804b19c <---------+
```